# add new pane in kendo ui splitter

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-splitter

A want to add new panes to kendo ui spliter dynamically but it seems like it's not working.
Even in their website it doen't work: [Kendo ui splitter demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/splitter/api.html) (I'm talking about the append pane and insert pane)

Is it possible that they have added a demo of something that doesn't work, or am I missing something?

Comment: do you still need help with this?

Comment: In the meanwhile no... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug - apparently, the code is not calling the `_resize` method when it should (in `_addPane` and `remove`, as far as I can see).

Seems to be an easy fix though (add this code somewhere before you first create your splitter):

```
kendo.ui.Splitter.fn._addPane = function (config, idx, paneElement) {
    var that = this;

    if (paneElement.length) {
        that.options.panes.splice(idx, 0, config);
        that._initPane(paneElement, config);

        that._removeSplitBars();

        that.trigger("resize");
        that._resize();
    }

    return paneElement;
};

kendo.ui.Splitter.fn.remove = function (pane) {
    pane = $(pane);

    var that = this;

    if (pane.length) {
        kendo.destroy(pane);
        pane.each(function (idx, element) {
            that.options.panes.splice($(element).index(".k-pane"), 1);
            $(element).remove();
        });

        that._removeSplitBars();

        if (that.options.panes.length) {
            that.trigger("resize");
            that._resize();
        }
    }

    return that;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/LW6RY/)